# Sqllite query returns cursor with 0 rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to retrieve data using query from the sqlite database that was previously populated. But for some reason the query `returnscursor` with no rows.

So here is the portion where I tried to retrieve data:

```
        database.open();
    Cursor cursor = database.getComponentData("CONTROLS", null, null);

    int test = cursor.getCount();//This is the part where i test through the eclipse debugger whether there is  any rows return
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        get.append("Video controls : "+cursor.getString(1)+" Audio Controls : "+cursor.getString(2)+" Reader controls : "+cursor.getString(3));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Cursor cursor1 = database.getComponentData("LIST", new String[]{"'URL'"},"AUDIO");

    get.append("Video list : ");
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor1.isAfterLast()) {

        get.append(" "+cursor1.getString(1)+" "+cursor1.getString(2)+" "+cursor1.getString(3));
        cursor1.moveToNext();

    }
    cursor1.close();
    database.close();
```

And here is the portion in the database adapter where I queried.

```
public Cursor getComponentData(String whichTable,String[] whichColumn,String whichSection) {
    Cursor c = null;
    if(whichSection!=null) 
    {   
        return database.query(whichTable, whichColumn,"SECTION = '"+whichSection+"'",null, null, null, null);
    }
    else{
        return database.query(whichTable, whichColumn,null,null, null, null, null);
    }

}
```

This is the portion where i insert into the database previously:

```
                 database.open();
               ContentValues control = new ContentValues();
               control.put("VIDEO_CONTROLS",video_control);
               control.put("AUDIO_CONTROLS",audio_control);
               control.put("READER_CONTROLS",book_control);

               control_long =database.insertNewControl(control);

               ContentValues temp_list = new ContentValues();

                a_p=audio_playlist.split(",");
                v_p=video_playlist.split(",");
                b_p=booklist.split(",");
               for(int i =0;i<a_p.length;i++){
                   temp_list.put("NAME", "test");
                   temp_list.put("URL", a_p[i]);
                   temp_list.put("SECTION", "AUDIO");

                list_long=   database.insertNewListRow(temp_list);

               }
               for(int i =0;i<v_p.length;i++){
                  temp_list.put("NAME", "test");
                   temp_list.put("URL", v_p[i]);
                   temp_list.put("SECTION", "VIDEO");
                   list_long=    database.insertNewListRow(temp_list);

                   }
               for(int i =0;i<b_p.length;i++){
                 temp_list.put("NAME", "test");
                   temp_list.put("URL", b_p[i]);
                   temp_list.put("SECTION", "READER");
                   list_long=   database.insertNewListRow(temp_list);

                   }
                database.close();
```

Insert Methods in the Adapter:

```
    public Long insertNewControl(ContentValues controls_values) {
return database.insert("CONTROLS", null, controls_values);  
}
public Long insertNewListRow(ContentValues list_values){
return database.insert("LIST", null, list_values);  
}
```

Thanks for reading.

**Edit :**
Forgotten to mention this, If I were to `query()` from the database right after I have inserted these rows, I would be able to get rows out.But I were to query for these rows after I `close()` and `open()` again, cursor returns no rows.

Comment: did you verify that data is in the database (**BASICS**) ?

Comment: as in whether insert() returns a non "-1" value?

Comment: or check the db using an sqlite tool in eclipse.

Comment: Although I have not used the sqlite tool yet but for what insert() returns , that last time i check it did not return for error(-1)

Comment: may I know where can I find such a sqlite tool to check my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgotten to post the solution that i found ,

Basically what happen is that I forgotten to name the database at the constructor of the class where the database and tables were created. *epicfacepalm*

Answer (score 1):

deleted my answer bout `cursor` (first cursor)

cursor1 return null because you don't need to put `'` in between column name, just put `"URL"` instead of `"'URL'"`

also you don't need to test the count, `moveToFirst()` itself return a boolean, if the cursor is null, it will return false. so what you need to do is,

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //do what you want
}
```

Comment: regarding whichColumn : passing null is valid , but it's just discouraged

Comment: oh yeah, my bad i thought it will return null, will change my answer.

Comment: Even remove the apostrophe It still returning no rows but thanks for replying.